# Can I seperate users in VmWare to only access their own VM's by default?

Tags: virtual-machine, user-accounts, esxi, access-control

I am trying to create a practise enviroment in VmWare EXSi 6.0 using a single host where students could login using vSphere and create VM's for server install practise.

However, I want to prevent them from accessing and accidentally deleting eachother's VM's. Otherwise I want to give them full access to the VM's they have created.

I tried experiementing with custom roles but only got cases where

1. They couldn't access or create any VM's
2. They could access all VM's that were not created by root and also delete them

We have a total of six servers, but due to our school's budget we cannot afford to buy licenses for things like vCenter Server or even basic host licenses (most are running Evaluation Mode and have to be reset every 60 days). If you know that this problem may be caused by licencing please comment.

I seached for hours but couldn't find an appropriate solution from the internet.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: You could try to setup a resource pool per student. If I'm not mistaken you can assign rights based on those. At least if that feature is available in your version, I'm not sure of that.

Comment: @Seth That got me along, I decided to use to root to create a RP for each user that they can't remove. However they still can interact with the VM's under any RP even if I set them (the RP) as Read-Only. Will continue tomorrow...

Comment: Nice that it helped. Good luck with the setup! You might be able "remove" your pupils from a default user role which lets them see all the VMs and set specific permissions on the RPs so they're only able to see what's beneath those. You probably would need to adjust this every so often.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got a somewhat of an working answer on my own...

I created five anonymous user accounts with the same pw (U1, U2, etc.) and created a Resource Pool for each of them (RP_U1, RP_U2, etc.).

For each user's own RP, I assigned them a custom role that allowed them to power their VM's on and off and customize their settings (add/remove components, insert ISO and so forth). Everyone else only got the default "Read-Only" role to that RP.

So everything worked fine with standard use, but the problem was with creating and removing VM's. Because for those operations, the students needed permissions not only to the RP, but also at root level due to VmWare ESXi's permission heritance (see[VmWare ESXi's documentation on common operations](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-4D0F8E63-2961-4B71-B365-BBFA24673FDB.html) and  [on inheritance](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-03B36057-B38C-479C-BD78-341CD83A0584.html)). Because of that, if students could create VM's under their own RP, **they could also create them directly to the host folder.**

That was a small problem, so I figured out a "solution":

1. Students cant create or remove VM's at all
2. For each user (U) three VM's were created beforehand under their own RP: two for Windows installations and one for Linux (they can modify the sizes and other settings)
3. The (weekly changing) network admin will use root to respond to problems and create/delete VM's

This should work, however it's not as flexible of a solution that I had hoped. We are currently looking into purchasing licences for our servers for a more "built-in" solution.

Shout-out to @Seth for help.